# Ninject Dependency Resolver

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

The client which I am calling looks like this

```
  public class CmsClient : ICmsClient
  {
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly ICmsSettings _cmsSettings;

    public CmsClient(HttpClient client, ICmsSettings cmsSettings)
    {
        _client = client;
        _cmsSettings = cmsSettings;
    } 
  }
```

In NInjectWebCommon.cs file I am resolving like this.

```
  kernel.Bind<ICmsClient>().To<CmsClient>()
```

This is not working as the constructor is expecting httpClient and cmsSetting class.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell your kernel how to resolve those types -

```
kernel.Bind<ICmsClient>().To<CmsClient>();
kernel.Bind<ICmsSettings>().To<CmsSettings>();            
kernel.Bind<HttpClient>().ToSelf();

var client = kernel.Get<ICmsClient>();
```